# Flutter how to remove space or padding from SfRadialGauge

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using SfRadialGauge plugin its working fine but there I am facing 2 issues.

1. Its showing lot of space on top, if I give height to container the sizes of SfRadialGauge is reducing also the top space I don't want to reduce size I just want to remove the space
2. Same space in GaugeAnnotation. I have column inside GaugeAnnotation and need to show little on top.

My code

```
  Widget getSemiCircleProgressStyle() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      child: Container(
          child: SfRadialGauge(axes: <RadialAxis>[
            RadialAxis(
                showLabels: false,
                showTicks: false,
                startAngle: 180,
                canScaleToFit: true,
                endAngle: 0,
                radiusFactor: 0.8,
                axisLineStyle: AxisLineStyle(
                  thickness: 0.1,
                  color: const Color.fromARGB(30, 0, 169, 181),
                  thicknessUnit: GaugeSizeUnit.factor,
                  cornerStyle: CornerStyle.startCurve,
                ),
                pointers: <GaugePointer>[
                  RangePointer(
                      value: 100,
                      width: 0.1,

                      sizeUnit: GaugeSizeUnit.factor,
                      enableAnimation: true,
                      animationDuration: 100,
                      animationType: AnimationType.linear,
                      cornerStyle: CornerStyle.bothCurve)
                ],
                annotations: <GaugeAnnotation>[
                  GaugeAnnotation(
                      positionFactor: 0,
                      widget: Container(
                        child: Stack(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,

                          children: [

                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                  child: RatingBarIndicator(
                                    rating: 0.2,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Icon(
                                      Icons.star,
                                      color: Color(0xffF4D03F),

                                    ),
                                    itemCount: 1,
                                    itemSize: 45.0,
                                    direction: Axis.vertical,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                RichText(
                                  text: new TextSpan(
                                    // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
                                    // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14.0,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                    children: <TextSpan>[
                                      new TextSpan(
                                          text: '2',
                                          style: new TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 40, fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular')),
                                      new TextSpan(
                                          text: ' /5',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 25,
                                              color: Colors.grey[400],
                                              fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular')),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'FIFTEEN DAYS SCORE',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.grey[400], fontFamily: 'UbuntuMedium'),
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ))
                ]),
          ])),
    );
  }
```

This is how its look like

[image]

I have marked the space with red pen. IF any one can help to reduce these spacing I am stuck on this from a day :(

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I guess I'm late but hopefully this can be useful to others.

## Premises

**Note. At the moment I can't find a way to have FULL control of this widget's white space. I only have found the following workaround to get rid of the white space *above* and *under* the gauge.**

The library's devs [mentioned](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/156564/cant-remove-whitespace-above-or-below-radialgauge-when-creating-a-half-gauge) two things:

1. "... For better understanding, say if the container has different width and height (say 300x800), we will always take the lowest dimension (here it is the width) to render the radial gauge ..."
2. "... We are sorry that we cannot provide any workaround to trim ..."
3. "... as this is the default rendering behaviour of the Radial gauge, we cannot consider your suggestion as a feature request."

The first statement is really useful, as it enables a workaround (see below).

The second statement.. I disagree, that's not something "impossible" to work around with.

The third statement... well that's just depressing.

## Workaround

Thanks to the Flutter DevTools, I noted that the Gauge renders a `NeedlePointer` Widget, which is the one rendering the cursed white space. As the devs mentioned, the gauge takes as much space as it can in the smallest direction.

This means that as long as you restrict height and width, you should be fine. I don't know in which context your Gauge is, but in mine the following code works great.

```
return LayoutBuilder(
  (context, constraints) =>  Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
      height: constraints.maxWidth / 1.5,  // WORKAROUND
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: SfRadialGauge(...),
          ),
          MaybeSomeLabelsWidgets(),
          SomeOtherWidgets(),
        ],
      ),
  ),
);
```

So, the fundamental part here is the fact that height is restricted and that there's a `Flexible` Widget that lets the Gauge take minimum space. `LayoutBuilder` in my case/context is useful just because I wanted to render the plot with a "3x2" feeling.

As a last note, keep the `canScaleToFit=true`, so that your plot is centered (why is it called `canScaleToFit`? That's another mistery I guess...).

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Been having the same problem too.
I found that the solution is to set :

`canScaleToFit: false`

But, this only works if you use the default circular gauge. For the semi-circular gauge, it will still left some blank spaces at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to use the ClipRect widget. The following will discard the top 20% of the SfRadialGuage.

```
ClipRect(
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, 
    heightFactor: 0.8, 
    child: SfRadialGauge(...)
  )
)
```